# SwiftUI: How do I make TextField fit multi-line content?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield, swiftui

In the attached code example I get a lot of extra top-spacing in my TextField. If I change the content to only be a single line, say "content", then it fits snugly. How can I get the same tight-fitting behaviour the single line has for a multi-line text?

Previews and code were made with Xcode 11.1 / Swift 5.1

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldDemo: View {
    var content: Binding<String>

    init(content: Binding<String>) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Custom placeholder", text: content)
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct TextInputRowPreviews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        let content = "content\ncontent\ncontent\ncontent\ncontent\ncontent"
        return TextFieldDemo(content: .constant(content))
                .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
#endif
```

[image: Screenshot of preview when content is multi-line]

Here is the example if I change the "let content" line to

```swift
let content = "content"
```

[image: Screenshot of preview when content is single-line]

Comment: add `.lineLimit(nil)` and check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for the input, but that didn't make a difference

Comment: As I know there is solution for such dynamic line expansion using a textfield. Instead  use a textview.

Comment: even worse, if you set a bigger frame, the content won't be shown completely....for me looks like an Apple bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's no direct argument to manage multiline padding correctly. They are maybe underdevelopping. But the following will give you a straight workaround solution to what you are expecting.

```
extension String{
    var extraLines : String{ get{
         return self +  String(repeating:"\n",  count: self.components(separatedBy:  "\n").count - 1)
    }}
 }


struct TextFieldDemo: View {
var content: Binding<String>

init(content: Binding<String>) {
    self.content = content
}

@State var height : CGFloat? //current height

let constHeightRatio : CGFloat = 0.55 //use for assembly with other fonts.
let defaultHeight : CGFloat = 250 //use for assembly with other views.

var body: some View {
    TextField("Custom placeholder", text: content).environment(\.multilineTextAlignment, .center).alignmentGuide(.bottom) { (ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat in
        if self.height == nil {self.height = ViewDimensions.height}
            return  ViewDimensions.height
    }.frame( height: (height ?? defaultHeight) * constHeightRatio, alignment: .bottom).background(Color.yellow)
}
}



#if DEBUG
struct TextInputRowPreviews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
    let content = "content\ncontent\ncontent".extraLines
    return
         TextFieldDemo(content: .constant(content))
}
}
#endif
```

This works fine for single view. If view assembly is required (with other stacking views, etc), you may adjust  `defaultHeight` and/or `constHeightRatio` to achieve what you want. Hopefully it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like this must be the direction to go. However, when executing this, I get the warning "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behaviour." On the iPhone simulator it gave almost the correct view, in preview it became too small and on the iPad with Swift Playgrounds it got too big.

Comment: Yes. You need to set `defaultHeight` when possible. Basically, you just provide different value for different size class. As you see UITextView is not implemented in SwiftUI,  If you do need multiline now, I suggest you use `Text` as a display output it can manage multiline well while using a textfield for one line input. That means instead showing a textfield, you show a TEXT. when you click it, you may replace it with a separate textfield.